# Sending and receiving data to a server machine in flask

Tags: python-3.6, flask-restful

I am having some values in my local machine which has to be sent to a server machine with some  IP : `10.127.206.114`(this is a VM server ) , which will consumed by the local Host service of VM (`127.0.0.1:5000/process`) , how can I build this service in my local machine . Right now I tried some what like this for  hosting

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__) 
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return (json.dumps({'Id':1234})
```

This will simply display `id:1234` In browser , how to send this data to the specified IP address `10.127.206.114` and consumed by a program running in `127.0.0.1:5000/process`

Answer (score 0):

You can use requests or urllib2 to send the POST request with Json data to another server.

```
from flask import Flask
import json
import urllib2

app = Flask(__name__) 
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    data = {
        'Id':1234
    }

    req = urllib2.Request('http://10.127.206.114/process')
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')  
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
    return (json.dumps(response)
```

If you don't specify the header, it will be the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` type.

Comment: But how it will reach `10.127.206.114` server machine ?I need to communicate with this machine first (inside this I have local Host)